# How can I iterate imported svg image in React

Tags: reactjs, arrays, svg, tailwind-css

I started to code a few months ago and creating my portfolio using React and Tailwind recently.
I imported a bunch of the svg images into the file I want to use and I am wondering if I can iterate these images.
I refered to https://dev.to/mohammedasker/how-to-add-svg-images-in-react-1h2g for importing images.

```
import React from "react";
import { ReactComponent as JavaScript } from "../../assets/javascript.svg";
import { ReactComponent as ReactLogo } from "../../assets/react.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Html } from "../../assets/html-5.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Css } from "../../assets/css-3.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Sass } from "../../assets/sass.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Bootstrap } from "../../assets/bootstrap.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Tailwind } from "../../assets/tailwindcss-icon.svg";
import { ReactComponent as MaterialUi } from "../../assets/material-ui.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Node } from "../../assets/nodejs.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Express } from "../../assets/express.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Firebase } from "../../assets/firebase.svg";
import { ReactComponent as PostgreSql } from "../../assets/postgresql.svg";
import { ReactComponent as MySql } from "../../assets/mysql.svg";

const Skill = () => {
  
  return (
    <div
      name="skill"
      className="max-w-7xl pb-[15rem] mx-auto flex flex-col my-20"
    >
      <h2 class="text-xl text-[#a6a6a6] text-center z-10">
        &lt;!- - - - - Skills - - - - -&gt;
      </h2>
      <div class="mt-16 flex flex-col md:flex-row justify-center">
        <div className="hard-skill flex flex-col mx-20">
          <h1 class="text-2xl neon-green text-center z-10">Hard Skills</h1>
          <div className="skill" class="flex flex-wrap justify-center w-60 z-10">
            <JavaScript class="w-[60px] h-[60px] m-2 p-3 bg-[#36393e] rounded-2xl shadow-xl shadow-gray-900" />
            <ReactLogo class="w-[60px] h-[60px] m-2  p-3 bg-[#36393e] rounded-2xl shadow-xl shadow-gray-900" />
            <Html class="w-[60px] h-[60px] m-2  p-3 bg-[#36393e] rounded-2xl shadow-xl shadow-gray-900" />
            <Css class="w-[60px] h-[60px] m-2  p-3 bg-[#36393e] rounded-2xl shadow-xl shadow-gray-900" />
            <Sass class="w-[60px] h-[60px] m-2  p-3 bg-[#36393e] rounded-2xl shadow-xl shadow-gray-900" />
            <Bootstrap class="w-[60px] h-[60px] m-2  p-3 bg-[#36393e] rounded-2xl shadow-xl shadow-gray-900" />
            <Tailwind class="w-[60px] h-[60px] m-2  p-3 bg-[#36393e] rounded-2xl shadow-xl shadow-gray-900" />
            <MaterialUi class="w-[60px] h-[60px] m-2  p-3 bg-[#36393e] rounded-2xl shadow-xl shadow-gray-900" />
            <Node class="w-[60px] h-[60px] m-2 p-3 bg-[#36393e] rounded-2xl shadow-xl shadow-gray-900" />
            <Express class="w-[60px] h-[60px] m-2 p-3 bg-[#36393e] rounded-2xl shadow-xl shadow-gray-900" />
            <Firebase class="w-[60px] h-[60px] m-2 p-3 bg-[#36393e] rounded-2xl shadow-xl shadow-gray-900" />
            <PostgreSql class="w-[60px] h-[60px] m-2 p-3 bg-[#36393e] rounded-2xl shadow-xl shadow-gray-900" />
            <MySql class="w-[60px] h-[60px] m-2 p-3 bg-[#36393e] rounded-2xl shadow-xl shadow-gray-900" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Skill;
```

I tried ↓ but didn't show anything.

```
const Skill = () => {
  const skillsArray = [JavaScript, ReactLogo, Html, Css, Sass, Bootstrap, Tailwind, MaterialUi, Node, Express, Firebase, PostgreSql, MySql];
  return (
    <div
      name="skill"
      className="max-w-7xl pb-[15rem] mx-auto flex flex-col my-20"
    >
      <h2 class="text-xl text-[#a6a6a6] text-center z-10">
        &lt;!- - - - - Skills - - - - -&gt;
      </h2>
      <div class="mt-16 flex flex-col md:flex-row justify-center">
        <div className="hard-skill flex flex-col mx-20">
          <h1 class="text-2xl neon-green text-center z-10">Hard Skills</h1>
          <div className="skill" class="flex flex-wrap justify-center w-60 z-10">
            {skillsArray.map((skill) => (
              <div class="w-[60px] h-[60px] m-2 p-3 bg-[#36393e] rounded-2xl shadow-xl shadow-gray-900">{skill}</div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Skill;
```

If you have any advice or suggestions I would appreciate it.

Comment: There was a typo in the `map` section of code that your talwind css class atrribute is not enclosed with `"`, but I had edited it. Please try your code now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can iterate over different components until and unless they don't have a basic similar structure. To use them in a map one thing you can do is to import the path of the images like this

```
import JavaScript from "../../assets/javascript.svg";
import ReactLogo  from "../../assets/react.svg";
import Html  from "../../assets/html-5.svg";
import Css  from "../../assets/css-3.svg";
.
.
.
.
```

NOw create the array as usual

```
const skillsArray = [JavaScript, ReactLogo, Html, Css, Sass, Bootstrap, Tailwind, MaterialUi, Node, Express, Firebase, PostgreSql, MySql];
```

And now define a component called `MyCompo` which takes `item`  as props like this

```
  const MyCompo = (item) => {
    //console.log(item);
    return (
      <div>
        <img class="w-[60px] h-[60px] .... " src={item.srcgiven} alt={item.altvalue} />
      </div>
    );
  };
```

And use them inside the map like this

```
      {array.map((item, key) => {
        return <MyCompo srcgiven={item} key={key} altvalue="imageq1" />;
      })}
```

You can experiment from this [Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-image-example-forked-lj3eu7?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to import the image you tought me but I got this error. 
`export 'JavaScript' (imported as 'JavaScript') was not found in '../../assets/javascript.svg' (possible exports: ReactComponent, default)` . I am using react 18 and is this the plobrem?